# "Post an answer" link is not showing on Questions in Answers module Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have used **Answers** module for question and answer functionality in Drupal 7 but on questions the link of "Post an answers" is not showing..... Its working fine on fresh install . I have given all the permission to this module.
Please help me out ..Here is the link http://beta-box.info/pahcom/node/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the questions view you have to add new field nid and add another extra field Nid in that you have to choose out put this field as a link in the options and provide the link path. so the link can point out the path of answers module
.